# Plotting a Horizontal Bar Chart with JQPlot

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I need to create a horizontal bar chart in an app. My bar chart needs to look something like the following (not to scale):

```
Item 1  |========14012===
Item 2  |=112=
Item 3  |======9012==
Item 4  |===321=
Item 5  |==================================165679==
Item 6  |32=
Item 7  |=======12312==
Item 8  |47=
Item 9  |5=
Item 10 |==================98765====
        ------------------------------------------------
          100                                   170000
```

Currently, I'm trying the following:

```
var data = [
  { "name" : "Item 1", "total" : 14012 },
  { "name" : "Item 2", "total" : 112 },
  { "name" : "Item 3", "total" : 9012 },
  { "name" : "Item 4", "total" : 321 },
  { "name" : "Item 5", "total" : 165679 },
  { "name" : "Item 6", "total" : 32 },
  { "name" : "Item 7", "total" : 12312 },
  { "name" : "Item 8", "total" : 47 },
  { "name" : "Item 9", "total" : 5 },
  { "name" : "Item 10", "total" : 98765 },
];

$.jqplot('myChart', [[[5, 1], [5, 3], [5, 5]]], {
  seriesDefaults: {
    renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
    shadowAngle: 135,
    rendererOptions: {
      barDirection: 'horizontal'
    },
    pointLabels: { show: true, formatString: '%d' }
  },
  axes: {
    yaxis: {
      renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
    },
    xaxis: {
      ticks: ticks
    }
  }
}).replot({ clear: true, resetAxes: true });
```

I'm not sure how to get my data in the jqplot chart. Partically the so that the labels on the left column reflect the names in my data. I keep reading the docs without any luck.

Thank you for any insights you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `$.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer` instead of `$.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer`

sample:

```
$.jqplot('myChart', [[[5, 1], [5, 3], [5, 5]]], {
  seriesDefaults: {
    renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
    shadowAngle: 135,
    rendererOptions: {
      barDirection: 'horizontal'
    },
    pointLabels: { show: true, formatString: '%d' }
  },
  axes: {
    yaxis: {
      renderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer 
    },
    xaxis: {
      ticks: ticks
    }
  }
}).replot({ clear: true, resetAxes: true });
```